# Rename columns on condition in python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a column in python dataframe which will be either `_00_test` or `00_test` . I want to rename the column to test.

What I want to do is check columns in data frame if either `_00_test` or `00_test` is present then rename the column name as `test`

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataFrame.rename` will not fail if the column is not in the dataframe.  So if we assume exclusivity, only one of the columns can exist in the dataframe, then you can do that in one go::

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'_00_test': range(5)})
>>> df
   _00_test
0         0
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
>>> df.rename(columns={'_00_test': 'test', '00_test': 'test'})
   test
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```